# Wordpress changed http to https but still not secure

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have updated every url to https in database and on cdns and image links everything but still the website is not secure. And when i keep clicking on the menu link of an page (at least 2 times ) then it becomes secure..  and only my homepage is not secure other pages are secure..

Please help thnx

Comment: Have you tried in clearing your cache or on incognito window?  It's possible you have a caching issue.  Also, you also need to set up your site to that any access to http version is redirected to https version, if you have not done that.

Comment: yes i have done both the things u said.. still the same result..

Comment: ok its been fixed .. and the problem was elementor using old http images in css